# Travis can't see a GitHub repo that I've transferred?

Tags: github, travis-ci

UPDATE: If this is you, go to your Travis profile page and click 'Sync' :)

---

I am using Travis CI on an open source repository. I've just transferred ownership of the repo on GitHub to an organisation I own, and also renamed the repository, and now I'm having a few problems making Travis work.

Travis was running fine when the repo was at `myname/myrepo`. Now I've transferred the repo to `myorganisation/mynewname`. I am the owner of `myorganisation` and the organisation has granted third-party access to Travis.

When I go to https://travis-ci.org/profile/myname, none of this seems to have updated:

1. `myorganisation` does not show up in the left-hand list of organisations, even though I am the owner of the organisation on GitHub and I've definitely granted Travis access to the organisation.
2. The old repo `myname/myrepo` is still showing up in the list of myname's repos on Travis. If I try to uncheck it in the Travis UI, I see: `An error happened when we tried to alter settings on GitHub. It may be caused by API restrictions, please review and add your authorized Orgs.`
3. When I push to the repo now, it does not automatically kick off a Travis build. If I try to run a build on `myname/myrepo` manually in Travis, it looks as though Travis is still pointing at the last commit before the transfer.

I've tried signing in and out of Travis, but it hasn't helped.

Basically it looks as though Travis hasn't spotted the move, and doesn't have any way to pick it up automatically.

How can I fix this?

Comment: UPDATE: Just tried clicking 'Sync' on the profile page. That solved all the problems!